# Getting unix timestamp

Tags: vb.net

Its a pretty simple question but I couldnt find nothing about it.

I would like to get the current unix timestamp in seconds, I would like to get the identical result as the PHP's `time()` function.

`System.Now` returns full date with the current time.

How can I achieve this in vb.net?

Answer (score 2):

I belive this will do it:

```
Public Shared Function GetUnixTimestamp () As Double
    Return (DateTime.Now - new DateTime (1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds
End Function
```